# Best practice: Design pattern for 2D HUD screen navigation

Tags: java, android, user-interface, design-patterns, state-pattern

If you have an application with a GUI totally working on 2D drawing, what should be the best practice to handle what to draw and where to touch?

An example for better understanding:
I have a game with a map. On this map I can build houses and stuff.
I also have an information bar which can be extended. On the extended bar I draw some information about the game and it also offers the interface to change different values. If a touch occurs, I have to check if the information bar is extended or not, to determine if I want to change something on the map or something on the bar.

That's done by the State Pattern, but I have some doubt if that's the right one because I think it can be a bit complex because of possible "sub-states".

So basically the question: Is the State Pattern (from GoF) the best practice to handle a pure graphical GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way this typically works is that the UI is a tree of Control objects. Each Control has some bounding box, and potentially a number of child controls which float above it. When a click occurs, the tree is walked from top-down (which means children before parents, and siblings in order). For each control, you see if the point intersects its bounding box. If so, give the control a chance to handle the click (i.e. some virtual `OnClick` method). If it does, stop processing, that click is done. Otherwise, keep walking until you get to a control that does handle it.

Comment: Thats what I have done to be able to build and position stuff on the map but thats not a complete answer for me. What about the states which determines, if a bounding box is even active? In your case, I have to handle multiple states for each control object. Currently I try to adapt the activity pattern of android for my case. Each different "screen" has his own state implementation with `onTouch(), onDraw(), onStateChange()`

Comment: Most UI systems will also have `visible` or `enabled` states that can be set on a given widget. Disabling it will prevent it from receiving clicks. The chore then is keeping that enabled state in sync with the back-end game state that affects it. Event systems can help there.

Comment: that sounds better... I will try to implement it this way. thx